# Memory problem in NSXMLParser (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, nsdate, nsxmlparser

Hi I'm trying to parse an xml and use the currentElementValue inside a code to get an expiredate. This is the code.

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"utlop"]) {
    NSDate *now = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    int numberOfDays = [currentElementValue intValue];
    NSDate *expireDate = [now addTimeInterval:60*60*24*numberOfDays];
    NSString *expireString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:expireDate];
    NSLog(@"ExpiryString :%@", expireString);



    //Add values to Vare
    enVare.utlop = expireString;
    enVare.enhet = enhet;
    enVare.isDirty = NO;

    //Add Vare
    [appDelegate addVare:enVare];


    //Releasing
    [dateFormat release];
    [enVare release];
    enVare = nil;
    [currentElementValue release];
    currentElementValue = nil;
    [expireString release];
    expireString = nil;
```

This results in a memory leak, but Im new to objective C so I can't find the error. When I just do this, it works:

```
 enVare.utlop = currentElementValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not release objects that are not owned by you. You own an object when u create them using `new` or `alloc`. Release only those objects that are created by you using these functions. Also make sure that you release such objects once you have finished using them.

Comment: But I have allocated enVare and currentElementValue as well further up the code. That's why  this works: enVare.utlop = currentElementValue;
No problems when I do this.

Comment: If u want to find details of the leak pls Build and Analyze the project. Can you say in which line does the leak occur after you analyze the project

Comment: expireString shouldn't need releasing as you don't alloc or retain it.